# MongoDB Aggregation - Conditional $lookup depending if a field exists or not

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization, aggregation

I have two collections called `collection1`, and `collection2` and they are structured as follows,

// collection1

```
[
  { "_id": 100, "text": "i am good", "history":[{"date":"2023-6-1", "updated":"2023-6-2"}] },
  { "_id": 101, "text": "i am naughty"}
]
```

// collection2

```
[
  { "_id": 1,collection1Id:100, "date":"2023-6-1", "updated":"2023-6-2" },  // is present in 1 so should not goto this collection
  { "_id": 2,collection1Id:101, "date":"2023-7-3", "updated":"2023-7-5" }
]
```

I want the aggregation query to run such that if the field (`history`) does not exist inside `collection1` then lookup to `collection2` should be made. See the code below:

```
db.collection1.aggreagte([

if history is not exist in collection1
{
lookup from collection2
}

])
```

**Expected Output**

After the aggregation executes, I want the result to be shown below:

```
[
  { "_id": 100, "text": "i am good", "history":[{"date":"2023-6-1", "updated":"2023-6-2"}] },
  { "_id": 2,"text": "i am naughty", "history":[{"_id": 2, collection1Id: 101, "date":"2023-7-3", "updated":"2023-7-5"}],  } // history has been taken from collection 2 
]
```

The first row is from `collection1` only because history exists and the second record is from `collection2` where I did lookup as the `history` field did not exist in the primary collection.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to have conditional stages?](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/is-it-possible-to-have-conditional-stages/127857?u=abdul_rauf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible to conditional `$lookup` join another collection.

But, you can achieve create the `history` field if the `history` field is missing then assign it with the `collection2` value. Otherwise, remain its existing value.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection2",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "collection1Id",
      "as": "collection2"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      history: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              {
                $type: "$history"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$collection2",
          "else": "$history"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "collection2"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4vom34-f7h2)

Comment: Please tell me why unset collection2 at end?

Comment: Hi, this is to remove the field `collection2` from the document in order to achieve the expected result.

Comment: but why use it? when it will be executed?

Comment: You can try with the Mongo Playground link I shared in the answer post, comment/remove the `$unset` stage and execute, you will see the output